# Format a print output in a specific way

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

let's say I have a pre-described list

```
l = [2333, 1212, 1000, 5000, 3000, 4000, 7000, 2918, 7665, 1982, 2900]
```

And I already made a sorting algorithm to sort it out.

I made a for loop to iterate in the list so that it would print in this manner:

```
1000, 1212, 1982, 2333, 2900, 2918, 3000, 4000, 5000, 7000, 7665
```

My code goes like this:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    
    print(l[i], end=" ")
```

However the output that I received was:

```
1000 1212 1982 2333 2900 2918 3000 4000 5000 7000 7665
```

How do I make it print to look like this:

```
1000, 1212, 1982, 2333, 2900, 2918, 3000, 4000, 5000, 7000, 7665
```

Here's a snippet of the sorting algorithm that I made:

```
l = [2333, 1212, 1000, 5000, 3000, 4000, 7000, 2918, 7665, 1982, 2900]

def myselection(list):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        minimum = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(l)):
            if l[minimum] > l[j]:
                minimum = j

        (l[i], l[minimum]) = (l[minimum], l[i])

myselection(list)

for i in range(len(l)):
    
    print(l[i], end=" ")
```

tried using join and map functions but it didn't work. I hope you can help me on this. Merry Christmas!

Comment: 1. Don't use your own sorting algorithm, unless its for practice (use the built in `sort()` function). 2. `", ".join(l)` will join items in your list with ", ".

Comment: Noted with thanks! However this is for practice. I would like to further expand my knowledge.

Comment: Sure - just know that anything (1 to 1) written in C is (99.99999% of the time) going to be faster than anything in python.

Comment: l = [2333, 1212, 1000, 5000, 3000, 4000, 7000, 2918, 7665, 1982, 2900]
l.sort()
print(l)

this will sort the list with built in module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sep`

```
l = [2333, 1212, 1000, 5000, 3000, 4000, 7000, 2918, 7665, 1982, 2900]

def myselection(list):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        minimum = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(l)):
            if l[minimum] > l[j]:
                minimum = j

        (l[i], l[minimum]) = (l[minimum], l[i])

myselection(list)

print(*l, sep=',')
```

**Output:-**

```
1000, 1212, 1982, 2333, 2900, 2918, 3000, 4000, 5000, 7000, 7665
```

Comment: thank you verymuch! May I ask what does the "*l" in print(*l, sep=',') mean?

Comment: basically `*` operator is used in the list to unpacked all the list of items.. also it is quite handy when printing data in a raw format (without any commas and brackets) or any other format..

Comment: also `*` operator can be used as a repetition operator. ex `l=[5, 6, 7]` `print(l*2)` this will give the output `[5,6,7,5,6,7]` ..

Answer (score 2):

```
print(", ".join(l))
```

That should print the list, seperated by commas

Comment: I tried doing this but I received "TypeError: can only join an iterable"

Comment: can you provide a piece of your code? because you told, that I is an iterable

Comment: noted, I edited my post now and it is provided thank you!

Comment: You'll likely need to `map(str, l)` before joining, since the list is integers.